# Kill an Ajax Request in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am firing an Ajax request using jQuery. During the process, I show a loading text to the user till it reaches the success/errorhandler function. Is there a way to abort the request in middle of it. So that it doesn't goes to the success/errorHandler variable. One way I can think of is using a global variable. Is there a better method.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps is a start?

> $.ajax() returns the XMLHttpRequest that it creates. In most cases you won't need that object to manipulate directly, but **it is available if you need to *abort* the request manually**.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just call the abort() method of your request object.

It may be more complicated than this depending on the behaviour you are after [see here.](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_a_1.html)